# how to avoid typeerror while returning result from php to python

Tags: php, python

I have the following code in php and python,I return $result from php to a python handler and running into below error..how should I return in python so that I don't run into this error?

php

```
  $result = [
        "TRIGGER_STATUS" => "SUCCESS",
        "PW_LINK" => "https://pw.company.com/"
];
```

Python

```
    orderedResults = sorted(result['result'].items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['Order'])
```

Error:-

```
  File "\\data\workspace\username\pwp4plugin\UI.py", line 269, i
n <lambda>
    orderedResults = sorted(result['result'].items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['Orde
r'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `kv[1]['Order']` being passed to the `lambda` function being passed to `key`. Assuming the dict which Python has after doing `json.decode()` is this:

```
>>> result = {'result': {
...                      "TRIGGER_STATUS": "SUCCESS",
...                      "PW_LINK": "https://pw.company.com/"
...                      }
...           }
>>>
>>> # this is what .items() looks like:
... result['result'].items()
[('PW_LINK', 'https://pw.company.com/'), ('TRIGGER_STATUS', 'SUCCESS')]
```

So in the loop, index 1 is `'https://pw.company.com/'` and `'SUCCESS'`:

```
>>> for kv in result['result'].items():
...   print kv[1]
...
https://pw.company.com/
SUCCESS
```

1. So `kv[1]['Order']` is  attempting to lookup a *key* called 'Order' against each of the two strings. Whereas, what Python is expecting is an integer index to something in each of those strings. Example:

   ```
   >>> for kv in result['result'].items():
   ...   print kv[1][4]  # the fifth letter in each string
   ...
   s
   E
   ```
2. In the PHP associative array you've given, there is no *key* `'Order'`. So it's unclear to us what you were trying to use. What is `result` in Python once the PHP result is parsed?